# Get IP address from Android accessing a Windows WebService

Tags: web-services, ip

I have android clients that make request to my webservice in C#. If would like to keep track of the IPs used by the clients. I read about several way of getting the IP address from the Android device and then send it to the Server, or even get the IP address of a client from the server side. But I also read that both have problems, because malicious clients could fake their own IPs and so on.

So, having myself as the developer for the Android client side and also for the Windows server side, which is the best and more trusty way to get the IP if the client who is requesting a method in the server?
Permission like Read_Phone_State in the Android device will be difficult to get.
Also I heard about NAT address, so, getting the IP and the Port number would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

String sIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

I Don't know if there is a better solution or my reliable.